# Int and Float arrays give wrong results after adding numbers using loops

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, double

Doing some simple exercies with C++ and I'm stuck...
When my sum[t] array is declared as integer or float it sometimes outputs at the end some crazy values like for example 4239023 or -3.17802e+30 (despite the fact that I add only small numbers from range <-100; 300>). When I change it for double it works correctly. Why int and float don't work here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t=0;
    int n=0;
    int x=0;
    cout<<"Amount of sums: ";
    cin>>t;
    int sum[t];

    for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Sum no. "<<i+1<<". How many numbers you wish to add: ";
        cin>>n;
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Insert number "<<j+1<<" : ";
            cin>>x;
            sum[i]+=x;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        cout<<sum[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Elements of `sum` are not initialized, containing random garbage. `sum[i]+=x` adds a value of `x` to that garbage - the result is different garbage, but garbage nonetheless.

Comment: Note that ISO C++ does not support variable-length arrays. You appear to be using a compiler-specific extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize your array of sums to zeroes after you receive the value of `t`. You could do it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    sum[i] = 0;
}
```